# Automatic serialwise string generator followed by integer

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello every one I am working on my college project I am trying to make an windows application using sql server 2008 and visual c#. I am using grid view for input. Problem is when a new row is added the string does not increment. I mean my empid is at row[i] and cell[0] when i go on to next row the empid is same as in previous row according to my code it should increase by 1 from initial value The result which i want is

```
row[0]cell[0] = emp6;
row[1]cell[0] = emp7;
row[2]cell[0] = emp8;
row[3]cell[0] = emp9;
```

and yes i don't want to use row count (digit) as a Id integer because of duplicacy of employeeID in database so to avoid this i am using SQL COUNT to get initial value for ID.
here is my code please help me soon

```
void emp_id_generator(DataGridView dataGridView1)
{
  if (dataGridView1 != null)
   {
     for (int count = 0; (count <= (dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2)); count++)
     {
            int j = 6;  //this is what i want to increment
            Label l = new Label();
            l.Text = "EmpID" + (j);
            dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[0].Value = l.Text;
             j=j+1;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: The code `int j = 6;` instantiates j to 6 each time you go through the loop, I think you should declare `j` outside the loop

Comment: sorry I have tried something else its working now thanks alot

Comment: What is the value currently being assigned to you id field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way. 
J must be initialized outside the loop.
Have a nice day.

```
 void emp_id_generator(DataGridView dataGridView1)
        {
          if (dataGridView1 != null)
           {
                    int j = 6;  //this is what i want to increment
             for (int count = 0; (count <= (dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2)); count++)
             {
                    Label l = new Label();
                    l.Text = "EmpID" + (j);
                    dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[0].Value = l.Text;
                     j=j+1;
             }
          }
        }
```